# HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class, NullPointer Exception

Tags: jsp, servlets, struts

[image]

I am trying to implement CRUD using jsp, servlet & struts. Not sure what I'm missing but I'm getting following error when I click submit on my jsp. Can someone help me understand this issue?

Comment: Can you show the code that *produced* this error message? It is pretty difficult to come up with a conclusion without any hints.

Answer (score 0):

You're using method `readline` in your controller, which takes a null value.

That's why you're getting a nullpoint exception!

Comment: Please try to improve your spelling. Although high level English is not expected here, but you can get much better acceptance if you follow this [six simple spelling rules](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/my-question-was-downvoted-closed-because-it-was-full-of-grammatical-mistakes-wh/291370#291370).